# jQuery Rotate CSS meter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found some CSS that moves a needle like a VU meter. This mimics what I want to do. However it does a full animation from start to finish. Whereas I would like to make the change happen through a series of clicks. I'm trying to figure out how to do that and I am unsuccessful. I would like to know how I can make the needle move in the same way only through clicks

CSS

```
.gauge {
  position:relative;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.needle-assembly {
position:absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left:46%;
  height:100%;
  width:10%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.needle-holder {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:60%;
  width:100%;
}
.needle {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#A00;
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  left:40%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveNeedle
{
0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);}
60% {-webkit-transform: rotate(55deg);}
65% {-webkit-transform: rotate(50deg);}
100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(65deg);}
}

#gauge {
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: moveNeedle 5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="gauge" style="height:140px; width:140px;">
  <div class="needle-assembly" id="gauge">
    <div class="needle-holder">    
      <div class="needle"></div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#gauge').click(function(){
    $('#gauge').css({transform: 'rotate(45deg)'})                        
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xc3wnux/1/)

Comment: I wish I had a clue why people are down voting my question as well

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't move when you click it because you are setting it to a static value.

You need to change the value somehow.

```
var deg=45;
$('#gauge').click(function(){
    var t = 'rotate(' + deg +'deg)';
    $('#gauge').css({transform: t})     
    deg = deg+5;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4xc3wnux/6/

Comment: This is a guess at what you are going for.

Comment: Having reread the question and understood better I have deleted my answer. This is pretty solid - I had read it that you wanted an animation based on one click.